# Exception by using "Include" with Linq (getting child tables)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm new with linq and EF, I have this model:

company   0 - N contracts

contracts 0 - N subcontracts

contracts 0 - N employees

So, in order to get all the records on a single database call I tried using "Include":

```
var list= from comp in Db.Company
          from cont in Db.Contract.Include("Subcontract").Include("Employee")
          select new CustomObject
          {
             SomeInfo = comp.SomeInfo,
             .
             .
             .
             Contract = cont
          };
```

But the next exception is thrown:

```
Method 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Account.Models.Contract] Include(System.String)' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Account.Models.Contract]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Account.Models.Contract]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

I don't know if you doing `CodeFirst`, `ModelFirst` or `DatabaseFirst`. But it sounds like the the properties are named `Subcontract` and `Employee` instead of `Subcontracts` and `Employees`.

If so your query should

```
from cont in Db.Contracts.Include("Subcontract").Include("Employee")
```

//

```
from count in Db.Contracts.Include("NameOfThePropertyNotTheTableName")
```

This is caused because the default pluralization in Entity Framework.

You can disable Pluralization using

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

#### More Information

- [Entity Framework 4.0: Pluralization](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/19/entity-framework-40-pluralization/)

## Update

If you change

```
public partial class ML_Contratos
{
    public Nullable<int> idempresa { get; set; }
```

to

```
    public ML_Empresas ML_Empresas { get; set; }
}
```

You should can do

```
from cont in Db.ML_Contratos.Include("ML_Empresas") // ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry my bad, the original names are in Spanish, and I "translated" them to English just to make my question clearer. But in my real code I'm using the properties' name, not table's. I'm using the DatabaseFirst approach.

Comment: No problem. Please provide the code of your `Contract` class and the `DbContext`.

Comment: Wohoo! ;) I am totaly sure i can help you, but i think we need some tries. I am tired so i have to go to sleep soon. But at least tomorrow we got it. I will update my anwser in a few seconds.

Comment: Of course, it would be great if you can help me tomorrow! but anyways I'll try to fix it by myself today, I'll let you know if I'm able to fix it, Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: My answer is updated again. Hope this helps. See you tomorrow!!